# Почему не считывает имя фильтра? AngularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spa

Здравствуйте!
Хочу сделать динамическую генерацию фильтров для списка данных. То есть что бы при изменении обьекта "filters" менялось и содержимое странички..
Создаю обьект, который содержит массив данных про нужные мне фильтры

```
function DevCtrl ($scope) {
$scope.filters = [
    {
      'name': 'IP контроллеры',
      'filterName': 'IpCtrls'
    }, {
      'name': 'Беспроводная система',
      'filterName': 'Wireless'
    }, {
      'name': 'Лифтовая система',
      'filterName': 'LiftSystem'
    }
  ];
```

Массив обьектов device получаю из сервиса, который выполняет $http запрос.
В HTML view хочу вывести все это таким образом:

```
<div class="part" ng-init = "vm.getDeviceList()">
        <div ng-repeat = "filt in filters">
          <h1 ng-click = "show =! show" class="part__title " ng-class = "{'is-active': !show }" ng-hide="!(vm.devices|{{filt.filterName}}).length" ng-bind="filt.name"></h1>
          <div class="part__content " ng-class = "{'is-active': !show }" ng-hide="!(vm.devices|{{filt.filterName}}).length">
         <div class="part__item" ng-repeat = "item in vm.devices| filt.filterName " ng-click="choose =! choose ">                                
   </div>
 </div>
```

Не считывает имя фильтра во вложенном ng-repeat, а именно  ng-repeat = "item in vm.devices| filt.filterName ", выше считывает.

Подскажите, возможно я не правильно организовал фильтрацию? По моей логике должно работать...

Текст ошибки:

```
angular.js:13920 Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '.' is an unexpected token at column 17 of the expression [vm.devices| filt.filterName] starting at [.filterName].

at http://localhost:8014/js/angular.js:68:12
at Object.throwError (http://localhost:8014/js/angular.js:14555:11)
at Object.ast (http://localhost:8014/js/angular.js:14308:12)
at Object.compile (http://localhost:8014/js/angular.js:14771:31)
at Parser.parse (http://localhost:8014/js/angular.js:15700:29)
at $parse (http://localhost:8014/js/angular.js:15865:39)
at Scope.$watchCollection (http://localhost:8014/js/angular.js:17294:30)
at Object.ngRepeatLink (http://localhost:8014/js/angular.js:29767:16)
at invokeLinkFn (http://localhost:8014/js/angular.js:9934:9)
```

Comment: какую ошибку пишет в консоли браузера?

Comment: в данно случае injector: unpr (Unknown provider)

Comment: если {{filt.filterName}} -  то фейлит синтаксис

Comment: Добавь в вопрос полный текст ошибки из консоли, для отладки используй не минифицированную версию ангуляра, он тогда читаемые ошибки дает, а не ссылки

Comment: Я не минифицированную изпользую  и всегда такие ошибки выдает.

Comment: ты не прав. Проверь что ты подключаешь: angular.min.js, или angular.js. Возможно ты используешь какие-то сборщики, у которых есть задача минификации

Comment: Ага, понял, поменял текст ошибки, спасибо

Comment: похоже, что не понимает "." в названии фильтра

Comment: не только, даже если убрать точку - он не будет подставлять значение переменной, он будет искать фильтр по указанной строке

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данная возможно не реализована.

Основная проблема в том, что имя фильтра получается **до** того момента, когда есть переменные, и следовательно пытается найти указанную строку как есть.

Можно воспользоваться обходным путем из [аналогичного англоязычного вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21491747/apply-formatting-filter-dynamically-in-a-ng-repeat)

Создать фильтр, который будет вызывать фильтры:

простейший случай для вызова фильтров без параметров:

```
app.filter('applyFilter', function($filter) {
  return function(value, filterName) {
    return $filter(filterName)(value);
  };
});
```

Использование:

```
ng-repeat = "item in vm.devices| applyFilter:filt.filterName"
```