# Как правильно реализовать циклические запросы на сервер, не используя socket.io?AngularJs

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

Есть список обьектов, нужно следить за изменениями в их свойствах. Так как сервер не настроен для сокетов, приходится использовать циклические запросы, то есть функцию из контроллера я выполняю каждую секунду, но это вызывает странное поведение программы, слетают выбранные чекбоксы.
Функция которая повторяется:

```
function getDeviceList() {

    var data = {
        UserSID: store.get('currentUserSID'),
        Limit: 100,
        StartToken: 0
    };

    DeviceService.GetDeviceList(data)
        .then(function(response) {
            vm.devices = response.data.Device;
        }, function(error) {
            vm.error = error.data;
        })
};

setInterval(getDeviceList, 1000);
```

Инициализация в html:

```
<div class="part" ng-init="vm.getDeviceList()">
    <div ng-repeat="filt in filters">
        <h1 ng-click="show =! show" class="part__title " ng-class="{'is-active': !show }" ng-hide="!(vm.devices|{{filt.filterName}}).length">{{filt.name}}
                <label>
                <span class="part__multi-check">
                <input class="part__all-check" type="checkbox" ng-model= "masterChecked" ng-click = "vm.toggleAll(itemsResults, masterChecked)" ng-checked = "vm.getCheckedCount(itemsResults) == itemsResults.length && itemsResults.length > 0">
                <svg class="icon part__icon--all-check part__icon--check">
                <use xlink:href="#icon-сheckmark"></use>
                </svg>
                    <input class="part__intermed-checkbox" type="checkbox" ng-checked ="vm.getCheckedCount(itemsResults) < itemsResults.length && vm.getCheckedCount(itemsResults) != 0 && itemsResults.length > 0">
                <span class="part__intermed-check">
                </span>
                </span>
                </label>
              </h1>
        <div class="part__content " ng-class="{'is-active': !show }" ng-hide="!(vm.devices|{{filt.filterName}}).length">
            <div class="part__item" ng-repeat="item in (vm.devices|applyFilter: filt.filterName) | filter: query as itemsResults" ng-click="choose =! choose ">
                <svg class="icon part__icon is-active{{item.HealthStatus}}" ng-class="{'is-checked': choose} ">
                    <use xlink:href="{{'#icon-'+ item.Name}}"></use>
                </svg>
                <p class="part__text" ng-bind="item.Name">
                    <br>(00:AE:02:2C)
                </p>
                <label class="part__check">
                    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.isChecked" value="{{item.Name}}" class="part__radio" />
                    <span class="part__checkmark">
                        <svg class="icon part__icon--check" >
                            <use xlink:href="#icon-сheckmark"></use>
                        </svg>
                    </span>
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: внимание вопрос: почему не должны слетать чекбоксы? информация о чекнутости хранится в объектах из массива, ты меняешь его на новый массив в котором у элементов нет свойства isChecked и закономерно обновляется view

Comment: а про вот это `ng-hide="!(vm.devices|{{filt.filterName}}).length"` уже даже вопрос был у тебя же http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/549446/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0-angularjs

Comment: с этим ng-hide="!(vm.devices|{{filt.filterName}}).length" уже нету проблем, ниже в коде применено решение.

Comment: По самому вопросу смотри первый комментарий

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самым лучшим вариантом - реализовать в виде сервиса, который будет сверять данные с запросов, и генерировать соответствующие события.

```js
angular.module('example').factory('observeDevices', observeDevices);

observeDevices.$inject = ['DeviceService','$rootScope'];

function observeDevices(DeviceService,$rootScope) {
 
 var 
  POLL_TIMEOUT = 1000,
  isObserve = null,
  devices = [];

  return ({
   observe:observe,
   unobserve:unobserve
  })

  function observe(){
   if (isObserve !== null && !isObserve) return isObserve = null;

      DeviceService
       .GetDeviceList({
           UserSID: store.get('currentUserSID'),
           Limit: 100,
           StartToken: 0
       })
          .then(function(response){
           diff(response.data);
           setTimeout(observe,POLL_TIMEOUT);
          }, function(error) {
              vm.error = error.data;
              setTimeout(observe,POLL_TIMEOUT);
          })
  }

  function unobserve(){
   isObserve = false;

  }

  function diff(){
   //Тут проверяем наличие девайсов в devices, в зависимости от этого генерируем события
   $rootScope.$broadcast('devices:add',device);
   $rootScope.$broadcast('devices:remove',device);
  }

}



 //Где то в контроллере:
 observeDevices.observe();

 var addDeviceObserver = $rootScope.$on('devices:add',addDevice);
 //Добавить device в  vm.devices

 var removeDeviceObserver = $rootScope.$on('devices:remove',removeDevice);
 //Удалить device из vm.devices
 Отписываемся от событий
 $scope.$on('$destroy',function(){
  observeDevices.unobserve();
  addDeviceObserver();
  removeDeviceObserver();
 });
```

Comment: и как это поможет в вопросе?

Comment: Давайте порассуждаем. Насколько я понял по коду, вы заменяете целиком массив в контроллере. Вам необходимо сделать некий список девайсов, в котором девайсы могут удаляться/появляться в режиме реального времени. Я предлагаю вам вынести логику с получением/сверкой девайсов в отдельный сервис, накидав примерную архитектуру. А в контроллере только обрабатывать события, и в зависимости от их типов удалять девайсы из списка, или добавлять их. Данный способ не будет перезатирать все данные, код будет лаконичным, логика которая не должна присутствовать в контроллере, вынесена в сервис.

Comment: во-первых, я - не автор вопроса, во-вторых, описание того что делает код должно было быть сразу в ответе, а не в комментарии, в-третьих, если уже есть сервис хранящий устройства зачем делать еще один?

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш ответ помог мне с этой проблемой!